# How can I show out "<>" using HTML.from() in TextView?

Tags: android

May I know if there have any way to show out **"<>"** or something like **"<>ddd**" normally using 
**HTML.from()** in textview?

the character is all missing after that invalid HTML tag ...

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: example needed. as expected results

Comment: tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("!@#$%^&*()_+ ?<>yuityuiyewr7897239028390")); character is missing after <>

Comment: @Machael.HW.Wong, the above example text doesn't need `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: hello @Akeshwar, this is my testing code, for my real project, back end will return html tag, like <h1> xxxxx<> xx? </h1> < something like this, so HTML.from() should need to use. of cause I know it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1):

Use `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`
For example `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h1>Hello &lt;World&gt;</h1>"));`
This results in `Hello <World>`

Answer (score 0):

you should escape the characters, < is `&lt;` (Less Than) and > is `&gt;` (Greater Than)
so:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&lt;&gt;ddd"));
```

will output

[image: output]